# Minimizing $a+4d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ and $d$ be positive real numbers satisfying the condition that each of the products $ab,$ $bc,$ and $cd$ is equal to one of the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,$ or $9$. Determine the minimum possible value of $a + 4d.$

---

I used AM-GM to get $a+4d\geq 2\sqrt{4ad}=4\sqrt{ad}=4\sqrt{\dfrac{ab\cdot cd}{bc}}$. I'm not sure what to do next, since I need equality to occur ($a=4d$) and I need $a,b,c,d$ to be positive. If anyone could give some guidance I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is :
$$a+4d\geq 4\sqrt{ad}\geq 4\sqrt{\dfrac{1\cdot 1}{9}} = \dfrac{4}{3}$$ and this can happen when:
$$ab = cd = 1, bc = 9, a = 4d.$$
So $1 = 4bd = cd\implies c = 4b\implies 4b^2 = 9.$ Then you can back track and find $b = \frac 32, c = 6, d = \frac 16$ and $a = \frac 23.$ Be sure to check:
$$a+4d = \frac 23 + \frac 46 = \frac 43$$
and $$ab = 1, cd = 1 \text{  and  } bc = 9.$$